# Value in childnode getting overridden firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to push values to the child node, but it is getting overridden every time I push a new value. how to push value to the child node with the overriding problem?

[image: click here to see the code]

[image: click here to see the firebase realtime db console]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

One method could be to fetch the data first. So, before you set the data, try this:

```
var commands = database.ref("bots/" + bot.id + "/commands")
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => return snapshot.val());
```

What this does is it gets the current data from the realtime database and stores it into a variable called "command".

Now, to set your new value in, all you have to do is just add your new value to "commands".

```
commands[**your id here**] = {
    id: command.id,
    name: command.name,
    file: file
});
```

Then, all you have to do is push the "commands" variable to the database reference and you will see that your previous data is saved and you can add new data.